Open DjVu with an app that doesn't declare DjVu support
To open DjVu files on a Mac, I've downloaded Okular. Unfortunately Okular's Info.plist doesn't declare any supported file formats.
I've manually selected okular.app in Get Info > Open With > All Applications. Now, when I click on a DjVu file in Finder, Okular is started but the file is not opened. When I run
ps -wwp "$(pgrep okular)" -o command

it shows that the path to the DjVu file was not passed to Okular's binary
COMMAND
/Applications/okular.app/Contents/MacOS/okular

Running
open -a /Applications/okular.app PATH_TO_DJVU

produces the same result.
However, explicitly passing the path to Okular's binary works:
/Applications/okular.app/Contents/MacOS/okular PATH_TO_DJVU

Is there a way to force Finder to do so?

If I remember correctly, the open document action is implemented with AppleEvents. It's possible they didn't handle that in the code. Can you check with the developers?

There is an old bug report back from 2022: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=456058. No reaction from the developers.

Then there’s not much you can do. Maybe write a wrapper that registers as a viewer for djvu, which simply passes the path in the AppleEvent to okular?
